# Adding two lists and getting XML output in nested form

Tags: java, xml, list, object, jax-rs

I am having two lists of objects application and environments. I am adding these lists but I am getting output as one whole list of application and than the other whole list of environments.

I want it in a nested form such as one entry for application and environment and than second row for application and environment and so on

This is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public ArrayList<MyModel> Test(){

    System.out.println("inside test");

    List<ApplicationDTO> allApplication = applicationService.getAllApplication();

    List<Application> Applist = new ArrayList<Application>();
    List<Environment> Envlist = new ArrayList<Environment>();

    for(ApplicationDTO d: allApplication)
    {
        Application a = new Application();

        a.setApplicationDescription(d.getApplicationDescription());
        a.setApplicationId(d.getApplicationId());
        a.setApplicationName(d.getApplicationName());
        a.setAssignedTo(d.getAssignedTo());
        a.setCreatedBy(d.getCreatedBy());
        a.setCreateTime(d.getCreateTime());
        a.setModifiedTime(d.getModifiedTime());
        a.setOwner(d.getOwner());

        Environment e = new Environment();

        for(EnvironmentDTO en: d.getEnvironment())
        {
            e.setEnvironmentId(en.getEnvironmentId());
            e.setEnvironmentName(en.getEnvironmentName());
            e.setOwner(en.getOwner());
            e.setCreateTime(en.getCreateTime());

            Envlist.add(e);
        }

        Applist.add(a);
    }

    ArrayList<MyModel> obj= new ArrayList<MyModel>();
    MyModel mm = new MyModel();
    mm.setAppDTO(Applist);
    mm.setEnDTO(Envlist);
    obj.add(mm);
    return obj; 
    }
```

**EDIT**

I changed my class I have added List of Environment inside application and now I am getting list of all the environments inside application, but I needed one environments inside one application, other inside the next one and so on. What am I missing ?

```
    public List<Application> Test(){

    System.out.println("inside test");

    List<ApplicationDTO> allApplication = applicationService.getAllApplication();

    List<Application> Applist = new ArrayList<Application>();
    List<Environment> Envlist = new ArrayList<Environment>();

    for(ApplicationDTO d: allApplication)
    {           
        Application a = new Application();

        a.setApplicationDescription(d.getApplicationDescription());
        a.setApplicationId(d.getApplicationId());
        a.setApplicationName(d.getApplicationName());
        a.setAssignedTo(d.getAssignedTo());
        a.setCreatedBy(d.getCreatedBy());
        a.setCreateTime(d.getCreateTime());
        a.setModifiedTime(d.getModifiedTime());
        a.setOwner(d.getOwner());

        for(EnvironmentDTO en: d.getEnvironment())
        {
            Environment e = new Environment();

            e.setEnvironmentId(en.getEnvironmentId());
            e.setEnvironmentName(en.getEnvironmentName());
            e.setOwner(en.getOwner());
            e.setCreateTime(en.getCreateTime());
            Envlist.add(e);
        }

        a.setEnvlists(Envlist);         
        Applist.add(a);
    }
    return Applist;
```

Comment: did you generate an XSD and apply JAXB to it?

Comment: Shouldn't `Environment e = new Environment();` be inside the for loop `for(EnvironmentDTO en:` ? Also you are **not** setting `Envlist` anywhere in the `Application ` object.

Comment: @Shashank: I think that this will be the solution for his problem. Set a.setEnvironment(en); before Applist.add(a);

Comment: @ShashankKadne no I am not having envlist in application dto. I am having two different DTO classes for application and environments. I will post my classes, have a look

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT and tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: You want one Environment in one application, but your ApplicationDTO contains multiple Environments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an object which contains an application and a list of environments, like ApplicationWithEnvironments.

```
    List<ApplicationWithEnvironments > AppWithEnvlist = new ArrayList<ApplicationWithEnvironments >();        

    for(ApplicationDTO d: allApplication) {
        ApplicationWithEnvironments appWithEnv = new ApplicationWithEnvironments();

        Application a = new Application();

        a.set...

        appWithEnv.setApplication(a);


        for(EnvironmentDTO en: d.getEnvironment())
        {
            Environment e = new Environment();
            e.set...
            appWithEnv.addEnvironment(e);
        }

        AppWithEnvList.add(appWithEnv);
    }

    ArrayList<MyModel> obj= new ArrayList<MyModel>();
    MyModel mm = new MyModel();
    mm.setAppWithEnvList(AppWithEnvList);
    obj.add(mm);
    return obj;
```

Or you could have a list of Environments in your Application object, so you don't need the new ApplicationWithEnvironments object anymore.

Comment: What should I have in the class ApplicationWithEnvironments ? Do I have two lists in that class namely List<Application> and List<Environment> or some other attributes ?

Comment: You would have 1 Application property and 1 List<Environment> property.

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT and tell me what am I missing ?